# Changing domain of computer using powercli OSCustomizationSpec

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

We are trying to automate creation of VMs based on a spread sheet (csv file). These VMs will be based on the template. Template is specified in the sheet. The script works fine and machines are created. However, computer does not join domain. IP and computer name are successfully changed.

Need help in figuring out how to troubleshoot this issue. Following is the snippet used for setting the IP and domain.

```
     New-OSCustomizationSpec -OrgName "Company" -OSType Windows `
          -Description $vm.Description -Domain "mydomain" -DomainUsername "domainuser" -DomainPassword "password" `
         -ChangeSid -AdminPassword "newpassword" -Name wincli -Type "Persistent" -FullName "Windows Custom Spec"
           Get-OSCustomizationNicMapping -OSCustomizationSpec wincli | Set-OSCustomizationNicMapping -Position 1 -IpMode UseStaticIP -IpAddress $vmIP -SubnetMask $vmSubNet -DefaultGateway $vmGateway -Dns $vmDNS1,$vmDNS2 -Confirm:$false
     New-OSCustomizationNicMapping –OSCustomizationSpec wincli  -Position 2 -IpMode UseStaticIP -IpAddress $vmIP -SubnetMask $vmSubNet -DefaultGateway $vmGateway -Dns $vmDNS1,$vmDNS2 -Confirm:$false
     $custom = Get-OSCustomizationSpec -name wincli
     $NewVM = New-VM -ResourcePool $resourcePool -Name $vmname -Location $folder -Datastore $datastore -Template $template -OSCustomizationSpec $custom  -confirm:$true
```

Comment: [What happens when using the FQDN for Domain and UPN for username?](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1012314)

Comment: Check out [sysprep logs](https://kb.vmware.com/kb/2001932)

Comment: Looked at sysprep logs. The unattend.xml file has correct information about domain and user name / password. setup err is zero byte file so no errors. setupacct does not have any errors related to joining domain.

Comment: It worked after adding using the format of username as pointed by BenH. (Username: user@domain.xyz.com, domain: domain.xyz.com)

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this as solved. Would you add that below? We do not add answers to questions here. I have rolled the last edit back, but it is in the revision history if you need it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment from BenH was right on target.

It worked after adding using the format of username as pointed by BenH. (Username: user@domain.xyz.com, domain: domain.xyz.com)